# Error in installing imagick due to dependencies issue

Tags: php, ubuntu-16.04, imagick

Need to install imagick on 7.3 qa server.
Having dependency issues on ubuntu 16.04

```
root@ip-172-31-37-47:/home/zia# sudo apt-get install php-imagick
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php-imagick : Depends: php-common (>= 1:7.0+33~) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: phpapi-20151012
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.


LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
 1998  apt update
 1999  apt install php7.3 php7.3-cli php7.3-common
 2000  sudo apt-get install php-imagick
 2001  sudo apt-get update
 2002  sudo apt-get install -y php-imagick
 2003  sudo apt-get install php-common php7.3-common
 2004  sudo apt-get install php-imagick
 2005  sudo apt-get install php-common=1:7.3+33~ php7.3-common
 2006  sudo apt-get install php-common php7.3-common
 2007  sudo apt-get install php-imagick
 2008  sudo apt-get --fix-broken install
 2009  sudo apt-get install php-imagick
 2010  sudo dpkg -i php-imagick_3.4.0-4_amd64.deb  # Replace with the correct filename if using 32-bit
 2011  sudo dpkg -i php-imagick_3.4.0-4_i386.deb
 2012  wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/php-imagick/php-imagick_3.4.0-4_i386.deb
 2013  sudo apt-get install imagemagick libmagickwand-dev
 2014  sudo apt install php php-common gcc
 2015  sudo apt install imagemagick
 2016  $ sudo apt install php-imagick
 2017  sudo apt-get install php-imagick
 2018  sudo apt install php-imagick
 2019  sudo apt install php7.3-imagick
 2020  history
```

Comment: Please keep in mind that both Ubuntu 16.04 and PHP 7.3 are horribly outdated